# Why does it say loop without do?

Tags: vbscript

Ok, so i have been given the assignment to make a guessing game. I have it all done and ready, the only problem is when I try to run it says this:

[image: Windows Script Host]

```
Dim MAX, MIN
MAX = 99
MIN = 0
Randomize

Number = (Int((MAX-MIN+1)*Rnd+MIN))

Do Until Answer = Number
Answer = InputBox("Guess A Number Between:" & vbNewLine & "0 And 100", "Guessing Game:")
If Answer = "" Then
    Quit = MsgBox("Do You Wish To Quit?",vbYesNo,"Quit:")
    If Quit = vbYes Then
        WScript.Quit 0
    End If
Else If Answer = Number Then
    MsgBox("Congrats You Got It!")
Else
    MsgBox("Nope, Try Again...")
End If
Loop
```

Comment: I think it should be `Do` and then `Loop Until Answer = Number`

Comment: @Blorgbeard Hmm... can it not be either, so the loop can be one+ or zero+ runs?

Comment: It didn't work, it showed the same error window.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Got it; simple oops:

```
Else If Answer = Number Then
```

Should be:

```
ElseIf Answer = Number Then
```

Separating `Else If` is creating a new `If` block, throwing everything off.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens if you have another loop or IF blocks that aren't closed properly inside the main loop.